# How to obtain the Output variables in a Kogito Custom Task

Tags: java, bpmn, kie, kogito

I have created a Custom Task in my BPMN and have written a handler extending **KogitoWorkItemHandler**. The input values were obtained as the parameters and the result was pushed back as a `Map<String, Object>`. This was working fine in case of an single varaible.

When in case using multiple custom object inputs and expecting multiple custom object outputs, how to identify the specific output variable name corresponding to the same custom object as input, so that it can be assigned correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve, we can pick the ioSpec from the currently running Node instance and then get the **DataDefinition** of the variables we need to use as results.

```
 WorkItemNode node =(WorkItemNode) workItem.getNodeInstance().getNode();
        IOSpecification ioSpec = node.getIoSpecification();
        for(DataDefinition dataDefinition : ioSpec.getDataOutputs()){
            if(dataDefinition.getType().equals(fullyQualifiedName)){
                return dataDefinition.getLabel();
            }
        }
```

Here, the **fullyQualifiedName** is the name of the custom input object, whcih you can obtain from the input `workItem.getParameters().get(parameter).getClass().getName()`. It loops through all the output and finds out the name corresponding to the custom type of the input.